# Introducing a named parameter breaks jOOQ query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

To query a PostgreSQL 10.11 database, I am using jOOQ 3.12.4, which comes bundled with Spring Boot 2.2.

Let's assume I have built a query using jOOQ like this:

```java
final String[] ids = ...;

final var query = dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.in(ids));
final Map<String, List<MyTable>> changeDomains = query.fetch().intoGroups(MY_TABLE.ID, MyTable.class);
```

This code runs fine and produces the expected results. But when I refactor my query and introduce a named parameter (to reuse the query in multiple parts of my code), like this:

```java
final String[] ids = ...;

final var query = dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.in(param("ids")));
final Map<String, List<MyTable>> changeDomains = query.bind("ids", ids).fetch().intoGroups(MY_TABLE.ID, MyTable.class);
```

I suddenly start to get the following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar ...; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text = character varying[]
    Hinweis: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Edit: I get the same error when I use

```java
MY_TABLE.ID.in(param("ids", String[].class))
```

instead.

How can I solve or work around this problem?

Comment: Why are you creating a param?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I want to reuse the query in multiple parts of my code. Therefore, it should be possible to rebind the parameter and thus adapt the query to the actual needs of these code parts.

Comment: Can you try param("ids", String[].class)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tried, and I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A better solution to your code reuse approach

> But when I refactor my query and introduce a named parameter (to reuse the query in multiple parts of my code)

While you could use jOOQ this way (be careful, when mutating and reusing jOOQ queries in a non-threadsafe way!), it is generally recommended to use jOOQ in a more functional way, see e.g.:

- https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/

You don't gain much by re-using a jOOQ query, specifically, there's hardly any performance gain.

So, instead of this:

```java
final var query = dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE)
    .where(MY_TABLE.ID.in(param("ids")));
final Map<String, List<MyTable>> changeDomains = query
    .bind("ids", ids).fetch().intoGroups(MY_TABLE.ID, MyTable.class);
```

Write this:

```java
public ResultQuery<MyTableRecord> query(String[] ids) {
    return dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.in(ids));
}

// And then:
final Map<String, List<MyTable>> changeDomains = query(ids)
    .fetch().intoGroups(MY_TABLE.ID, MyTable.class);
```

#### The actual problem you ran into:

jOOQ, JDBC, and SQL don't support single bind value `IN` lists. While it seems useful to write this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IN (:bind_value)
```

And passing an array or list as a single bind value, this is not supported in SQL. Some APIs might pretend that this is supported (but behind the scenes replace the single bind value by multiple `?, ?, ..., ?`

PostgreSQL supports the `= ANY (:bind_value)` operator with arrays

```sql
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = ANY (:bind_value)
```

You could use it in jOOQ using

```java
dslContext.selectFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq(any(ids)));
```

That way, you could call the `bind()` method to replace the array prior to execution. However, I still recommend you write functions returning queries dynamically.